# compression webpack bundle using plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am trying to compressed webpack bundle using CompressionPlugin.
below my webpack setup

webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin")


module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public')
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
        'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),

        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                    beautify: false,
                },
                compress: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    warnings: false
                    }
                }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({   
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    })
],
watch: true,
module:{
    loaders:[
        {
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query:{
                presets: ['react','es2015','stage-1'],
            },
        },
    ],
},
};
```

www

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);


var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

index.ejs

```
<body>
    <DIV id="app"><%- reactComponent -%></DIV>
    <script>window.INITIAL_STATE=<%- initialState -%></script>
    <SCRIPT src="/bundle.js"></SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

i am getting the following bundle output 
[image]

everything seems to work but i am not sure if i am doing it in the corrct way,
I am not sure if it actually configured to use bundle.js.gz

Answer (score 3):

When the browser call reaches the server it must have the `gzip` encoding enabled: the request header must contain something like:

`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

All browsers [support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) but older browsers may not have it.

You don't have to add any extra `script` tags to get this to work. You reference the `js` file.

You are serving your files with a node http server that doesn't know what to do with `gzip` files unless accessed directly.

When getting a request that can handle `gzip`, the server should check if the requested file also has an archived version of it and serve that instead.

I haven't tested [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/jankuca/1360787) but it seems to be doing what you need: you have to adjust your node server.

When serving files with `nginx` or `Apache`, enabling `gzip` is a setting.

Hope it helps

Comment: So we need to deploy a project with both bundle.js and bundle.js.gz files?

Comment: If you are testing [this node implementation](https://gist.github.com/jankuca/1360787), no, you don't have to deploy the `gz` as this will be generated on request - not ideal.

If you are serving the static files with `nginx` or similar, yes, you have to deploy the `gz` files.